# SOLR: getting documents in the given order

Tags: solr, solr4

I have a following field in SOLR schema.

`<fieldType name="integer" class="solr.IntField" omitNorms="true"/>
    <field name="id" type="integer" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="false"/>`

If I issue following query:

`id:(1234 OR 2345 OR 3456)`

SOLR does not return the documents in that order. It is giving document with id 3456, then with 1234 and then with 2345.

How do I get it in the same order as in the query?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that by default Solr is sorting the documents by score (which if there is no text query is often times very random). You can do a workaround by adding a sort by in the query url like this: `sort=id+asc%2C+score+desc`.

Comment: I don't want to sort it based on id. Maybe, I have provided bad example. If I provide query like id:(2345 OR 1234 OR 3456), the documents SOLR returning, is not in the same order as that of query.